# Orbit with constant central force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

if a central force doesn't depend on the radius, its length is constant during moving.
I saw what its orbit looks like on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN_9_E-5sPA.
It seems that there are many radii correspond to one theta.

What is the orbit equation?

Comment: Contact YouTube, get the name of the person who published the video, and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, according to [Goldstein, H. (1980). Classical Mechanics (2nd ed.). Reading, MA: Addison-Wesley. ISBN 0-201-02918-9] page 88-89 there exist no analytical solution to the problem of central force with constant magnitude (that is with potential  $V(r)=kr^1$). Thus, I assume that, in the video, the equations of motions were integrated numerically and maybe the fact that $r(\theta)$ taking multiple values for the same $\theta$ might be a numerical artifact depending of the algorithm used to solve the system.

Although, one can show that such a potential yields stable orbits (see [Bertrand's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem)).